# Learning Java - function returns 0

Tags: java

I'm just learning Java... I have three classes which creates bank account

My first class;

```
public class Banka {

    protected static int pocetUctu = 0;
    public Ucet vytvorUcet(Clovek maj, double pocatecni) {
        Ucet uc = new Ucet(maj, pocatecni);
        pocetUctu++;
        System.out.println("Ucet " + uc +  " vytvoren");
        System.out.println("Pocet uctu " + pocetUctu);
        return uc;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Banka b1 = new Banka();
        Clovek pn = new Clovek("Petr Novotny", 1949);
        Clovek jv = new Clovek("Jan Vesely", 1970);
        Ucet pu1 = b1.vytvorUcet(pn, 1000);
        Ucet pu2 = b1.vytvorUcet(pn, 50000);
        Ucet ju = b1.vytvorUcet(jv, 3000);
        pu2.prevedNa(ju, 1000);
        ju.prevedNa(pu1, 500);
        pu1.vypisInfo();
        pu2.vypisInfo();
        ju.vypisInfo();

    }
}
```

My second class;

```
public class Clovek {

    protected String jmeno;
    protected int rokNarozeni;
    protected static int pocetLidi = 0;

    public Clovek(String j, int rN) {
        jmeno = j;
        rokNarozeni = rN;
        pocetLidi++;
    }
    public void vypisInfo() {
        System.out.println("Clovek:");
        System.out.println("Jmeno="+jmeno);
        System.out.println("Rok narozeni="+rokNarozeni);
    }
}
```

My third class;

```
public class Ucet {

    static double zustatek;
    static Clovek majitel;

    public Ucet(Clovek maj, double zus) {
        maj = majitel;
        zus = zustatek;
    }

    public void pridej(double pocatecni) {
        zustatek += pocatecni;
    }
    public void vypisZustatek() {
        System.out.println(zustatek);
    }
    public Ucet prevedNa(Ucet kam, float castka) {
        zustatek -= castka; // nebo také vhodné je: pridej(-castka);
        kam.pridej(castka);
        return this;
    }
    public void vypisInfo() {
        System.out.println("Vlastník" + majitel);
        System.out.println("Zůstatek" + zustatek);
    }
}
```

`pu1.vypisInfo();` should output account owner and his money on it, but It shows owner null and balance 0. Where can be problem ?

Comment: Just adding to @Reimeus' answer, it seems to me that zustatek and majitel variables shouldn't be static otherwise why would you want to assign constructor parameters to static variables and then printing them from a non static method vypisInfo()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment is from right to left

```
majitel = maj;
zustatek = zus;
```

Comment: God... thanks. I watched to that code more than hour and wasn´t able to find that.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

> ```
> public Ucet(Clovek maj, double zus) {
>     maj = majitel;
>     zus = zustatek;
> }
> ```

But you should have:

> ```
> public Ucet(Clovek maj, double zus) {
>     majitel = maj;
>     zustatek = zus;
> }
> ```